# Style.xml: Content is not allowed in trailing section

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting this error:......

Error: Content is not allowed in trailing section.

On Style.xml file:......

```
<color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>

<color name="bottomText">#6b6b6b</color>
<color name="rippleEffectColor">#f916a463</color>
```

Comment: 1. Colors should go in `colors.xml`. 2. That's not the entire XML file.

Answer (score 0):

Your application colors should be inside `colors.xml`. From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources#Color):

> **file location:**
>
> ```
> res/values/colors.xml
> The filename is arbitrary. The <color> element's name will be used as the resource ID.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This content should be is the colors.xml file not in Style.xml. please remove this item from style and add this on colors.xml locations in res directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<resources>

    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>

    <color name="bottomText">#6b6b6b</color>
    <color name="rippleEffectColor">#f916a463</color>

</resources>
```